# generate ID while Importing .sql file to database

Tags: mysql

I have a .sql file that I am importing into my database using phpmyadmin. Each time I have been going through the long list of values and changing the ID so it doesn't conflict with another entry. Since I don't care what the ID is, is there any way to have that auto generated?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `my_column` (`id`, `valueone`, `valuetwo`) VALUES
(1, 'some value A', 'some value B'),(2, 'some value C', 'some value D'),(3, 'some value E', 'some value F');
```

So in the above code, I don't want to type in the "1", "2", and "3".

Can I just leave this blank for it to auto generate? Or is there a symbol that I add instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add AUTO_INCREMENT to id column and remove it from the insert Statement:

```
    INSERT INTO `my_column` ( `valueone`, `valuetwo`) VALUES
( 'some value A', 'some value B'),( 'some value C', 'some value D'),(...
```